# Trying to compile java file without success on Ubuntu (CVE-2020-2555.java)

Tags: java, compiling, openjdk, compiler

I am trying to compile the following file https://github.com/wsfengfan/CVE-2020-2555/blob/master/supeream/CVE_2020_2555.java in my Ubuntu server but without success. I tried 'javac CVE_2020_2555.java' but returned with more then 17 errors:

```
javac CVE_2020_2555.java
CVE_2020_2555.java:5: error: package com.supeream.serial does not exist
import com.supeream.serial.Serializables;
                          ^
CVE_2020_2555.java:6: error: package com.supeream.weblogic does not exist
import com.supeream.weblogic.T3ProtocolOperation;
                            ^
CVE_2020_2555.java:7: error: package com.tangosol.util.extractor does not exist
import com.tangosol.util.extractor.ChainedExtractor;
                                  ^
CVE_2020_2555.java:8: error: package com.tangosol.util.extractor does not exist
import com.tangosol.util.extractor.ReflectionExtractor;
                                  ^
CVE_2020_2555.java:9: error: package com.tangosol.util.filter does not exist
import com.tangosol.util.filter.LimitFilter;
                               ^
CVE_2020_2555.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
        ReflectionExtractor extractor1 = new ReflectionExtractor(
        ^
  symbol:   class ReflectionExtractor
  location: class CVE_2020_2555
CVE_2020_2555.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
        ReflectionExtractor extractor1 = new ReflectionExtractor(
                                             ^
  symbol:   class ReflectionExtractor
  location: class CVE_2020_2555
CVE_2020_2555.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
        ReflectionExtractor extractor2 = new ReflectionExtractor(
        ^
  symbol:   class ReflectionExtractor
  location: class CVE_2020_2555
CVE_2020_2555.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
        ReflectionExtractor extractor2 = new ReflectionExtractor(
                                             ^
  symbol:   class ReflectionExtractor
  location: class CVE_2020_2555
CVE_2020_2555.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
        ReflectionExtractor extractor3 = new ReflectionExtractor(
        ^
  symbol:   class ReflectionExtractor
  location: class CVE_2020_2555
CVE_2020_2555.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
        ReflectionExtractor extractor3 = new ReflectionExtractor(
                                             ^
  symbol:   class ReflectionExtractor
  location: class CVE_2020_2555
CVE_2020_2555.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
        ReflectionExtractor[] extractors = {
        ^
  symbol:   class ReflectionExtractor
  location: class CVE_2020_2555
CVE_2020_2555.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
        ChainedExtractor chainedExtractor = new ChainedExtractor(extractors);
        ^
  symbol:   class ChainedExtractor
  location: class CVE_2020_2555
CVE_2020_2555.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
        ChainedExtractor chainedExtractor = new ChainedExtractor(extractors);
                                                ^
  symbol:   class ChainedExtractor
  location: class CVE_2020_2555
CVE_2020_2555.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
        LimitFilter limitFilter = new LimitFilter();
        ^
  symbol:   class LimitFilter
  location: class CVE_2020_2555
CVE_2020_2555.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
        LimitFilter limitFilter = new LimitFilter();
                                      ^
  symbol:   class LimitFilter
  location: class CVE_2020_2555
CVE_2020_2555.java:87: error: cannot find symbol
        byte[] payload = Serializables.serialize(badAttributeValueExpException);
                         ^
  symbol:   variable Serializables
  location: class CVE_2020_2555
17 errors
```

Any help would be very appreciated in order to build the serialized object (test.ser) with the following java code.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can be closed. Solved by compiling with JetBrains IDEA community edition.

Answer (score 0):

To run it using `javac` command, you need to specify CLASSPATH:

```
javac -cp /home/user/com/supeream:. /home/user/com/supeream/Main.java
```

I previously renamed `CVE_2020_2555` folder to `com`.

Steps:

1. `cd ~/`
2. `git clone https://github.com/wsfengfan/CVE-2020-2555.git`
3. `mv CVE-2020-2555 com`
4. `javac -cp /home/user/com/supeream:. /home/user/com/supeream/CVE_2020_2555.java`
   or
   `javac -cp com/supeream:. com/supeream/CVE_2020_2555.java`

It is important to be inside of `/home/user` directory. However, it requires more dependencies. So you are right. It is better to use IDE that will download required dependencies for you.